# how do I add objects of different types to a hashmap in Android?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to add various records to be added/retrieved by a single Key value.

Each data record should have the following parameters;

```
public class WebRecord {
        Integer UniqueCustomerID;
        Integer Count; // Number of websites for a given customer

//Repeat the following 'Count' number of times
       { // Each Record for a given Website for the same customer
    String BusinessName, Websites, siteTag;
    Integer uniqueWebID, BusinessTypeID;
       }

}
```

I want such records to exist based on count value  I get from a Web service.
I was going to use Hashmap as below:

Can someone tell me how to implement that data structure in a HASHMAP?
I want to put and get these records using a single key value UniqueCustomerID;

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with android specifically. You should remove the android tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not good with java concepts but I think you can do,

```
     class WebRecord{ 
          int UniqueCustomerID; 
          int Count;
     } 

     class ContactRecord{ 
        String BusinessName, Websites, siteTag; 
        int uniqueWebID, BusinessTypeID; 
    }
```

And in your java file

```
   MyActivity{ 
            public Map<WebRecord,ArrayList<ContactRecord>> map=new HashMap<WebRecord,ArrayList<ContactRecord>>(); 

        //now create one object of web record

        //create arraylist of ContactRecord depending upon "count" variable's value

        // fill the above both and put into map

            map.put(webRec, arrContact); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of `ContactRecord` objects equal to the `Count` value then you don't need to store that value explicitly.

Given your data structure above you could do.

```java
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ContactRecord>> map;
```

Where the key to the map is the `UniqueCustomerID`. To discover the `Count` value you can interrogate the list in the map like this.

```
map.get(customerId).size();
```